# What is ConstPtr&?

Tags: ros, callback, function

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All, I'm still new to ROS and C++. I'm having trouble understanding what the ConstPtr& does when writing the callback function for a simple subscriber:

```
 void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) 

     {ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());}
```

Wouldn't the code work with just:

```
 void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String msg)

      {ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg);}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212857/what-is-constptr&?/) by [OmoNaija](https://answers.ros.org/users/23049/omonaija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When messages are automatically generated into C++ code, there are several typedefs defined. One of them is `::Ptr`, which is typedef-ed to be a `boost::shared_ptr<MSG>`, and another is `::ConstPtr` which is `boost::shared_ptr<MSG const>`.

By passing a const pointer into the callback, we avoid doing a copy. While this might not make much difference for `std_msgs::String`, it can make a huge difference for `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 37

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OmoNaija](https://answers.ros.org/users/23049/omonaija/) on 2015-07-06**:
Thank You!

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2016-01-21**:
thanks a lot for your help

**Comment by [wy3](https://answers.ros.org/users/30862/wy3/) on 2017-07-29**:
but what does & means? If msg is already a pointer, why do we take the address of msg? Or does that & means passing by reference?

**Comment by [ksirks](https://answers.ros.org/users/31915/ksirks/) on 2017-09-15**:
@wy3: the ampersand (&) means pass by reference as you said.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-10**:
Note: today I think `boost::shared_ptr<>` is replaced in ROS by `std::shared_ptr<>`, since this is now part of the C++ Standard Library.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-10**:
@wy3, the `&` is to pass the `shared_ptr` object itself by reference. The `shared_ptr` object is a class which manages the object it wraps and "points to", and the `&` is to pass the `shared_ptr` object by reference. So, we are passing a message by a reference to a smart pointer which points to it--yeah, it's kind of a double-layered approach. In C you'd just pass the message by pointer and be done, but the added benefit of using a shared pointer, which is a type of "smart pointer", is that it automatically manages the storage duration of the memory (for the message) it points to, meaning you never have to manually free or delete this dynamically-allocated memory block for the message because it's done automatically when all shared pointers to that memory are gone or out of scope.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-10**:
I just added my above comments, and more, into my own answer here. I realized my comments were becoming more than just comments, so I made them into an answer.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2020-08-18**:
ROS1 still very much uses boost in roscpp - changing to std::shared_ptr would break the world. ROS2 does drop boost for std::shared_ptr in rclcpp.

**Comment by [ia](https://answers.ros.org/users/67147/ia/) on 2021-04-11**:
@ahendrix but why do some message type look like `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr` and others need colons like: `automotive_platform_msgs::AdaptiveCruiseControlCommand::ConstPtr`? For instance, without those double colons `::` right before `ConstPtr` I get a very hard to grok error message too long to post here.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2021-04-12**:
@ahendrix, I don't see the answer yet, but here's a question I asked to try to start to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67053471/what-is-a-void-stdallocator-ie-stdallocatorvoid.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to expound upon [the main answer here](https://answers.ros.org/question/212857/what-is-constptr/?answer=212881#post-id-212881).

`::ConstPtr` can be understood and read as **"shared pointer to a constant message"**, and `::Ptr` can be understood and read as **"shared pointer to a (modifiable) message"**. It's just a smart-pointer-based light-weight way of passing messages. Choose the correct one based on whether or not the recipient of the passed message will need to modify the message. Read more about `std::shared_ptr<>` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr.

Therefore, `::ConstPtr&` can be understood and read as **"reference to a shared pointer to a constant message"**, and `::Ptr&` can be understood and read as **"reference to a shared pointer to a (modifiable) message"**.

Today I think `boost::shared_ptr<>` is replaced in ROS by `std::shared_ptr<>`, since this is now part of the C++ Standard Library. See here: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/issues/319.

That means this is what these definitions would be today:

`::Ptr` is typedef-ed to `std::shared_ptr<MSG>`, which is a shared pointer to a message, and `::ConstPtr` is typedef-ed to `std::shared_ptr<MSG const>`, which is a shared pointer to a `const` message.

Addressing this question in the comments under the main answer:

> but what does & means? If msg is already a pointer, why do we take the address of msg? Or does that & means passing by reference?

The `&` is to pass the `shared_ptr` object itself by reference. The `shared_ptr` object is a class which manages the object it wraps and "points to", and the `&` is to pass the `shared_ptr` object by reference. So, we are passing a message by a reference to a smart pointer which points to it--yeah, it's kind of a double-layered approach. In C you'd just pass the message by pointer and be done, but the added benefit of using a shared pointer, which is a type of "smart pointer", is that it automatically manages the storage duration of the memory (for the message) it points to, meaning you never have to manually free or delete this dynamically-allocated memory block for the message because it's done automatically when all shared pointers to that memory are gone or out of scope.

So, passing a smart pointer saves potentially a TON of data and time in the passing of the message, and passing the smart pointer itself by reference rather than value saves a tiny bit more of data and time by not having to pass the entire smart pointer object, but rather just a reference to it. It is another small bit of savings in the message passing.

Also, I hate the names `::ConstPtr` and `::Ptr`. They create confusion. I think they should be named `::PtrToConstMsg` and `::PtrToMsg`, respectively. This is so much more clear and easy to understand. I recommend that ROS make that change.

---

Originally posted by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) with karma: 171 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adi](https://answers.ros.org/users/61632/adi/) on 2020-10-26**:
So if at some point I need to create a copy of the message that is a ConstPtr& msg, would I need to do **msg?

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-10-29**:
@adi, no, a `const ConstPtr& msg` is NOT a pointer to a pointer to a message, it is a *reference* to a smart pointer to a message. You treat references *the same as if they were the object itself*. Do some reading up on references in C++. So, you'd only need to dereference the one smart pointer (`shared_ptr`) with a single asterisk (`*`), like this: `*msg`.

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-12-03**:
In someone's code I've seen:

```
void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr &msg)
```

Does it matter if the & is in front of `msg` instead of at the end of `ConstPtr`? How is this different? Is the message being passed as a reference instead of the pointer? What does that imply?

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-12-03**:
@jorgemia, it makes no difference. `const type& msg` and `const type &msg` are the same thing--personal style preference. This is a generic C++ question, so feel free to search around the internet, but where you put the space around reference (`&`) and pointer (`*`) symbols doesn't matter. Just choose one you like and stick with it, or do whatever the code you are working in does. Also, go do some reading on references and pointers in C++. To pass a raw pointer, you might define a function: `void myfunc(sometype * ptr)`, and you call it with `myfunc(&variable)`. To pass a reference, you might define a function: `void myfunc(sometype& ref)`, and you call it with `myfunc(variable)`. In a definition, `&` means "reference", but outside of a definition, it means "address of". In a definition, `*` means "pointer to" (which is an address), but outside a definition, it means "contents of" (ie: contents of an address or pointer--ie: what is being pointed TO).

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-12-03**:
@jorgemina, here are 3 things you need to go spend 1 to 5 whole days or so studying: 1) C/C++ pointers (sometimes called "raw pointers" in C++, so as to distinguish them from smart pointer objects), 2) C++ references, 3) C++ smart pointers, which are actually class objects which manage raw pointer memory and act like raw pointers.

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-12-03**:
Thanks for the detailed answer! Very useful! Yes, I just spent the last hour learning about pointers and references but hadn't seen the position of the & or * being mentioned anywhere, all the examples had it next to the type. Going to continue reading now!

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-12-04**:
I wrote this short program to try and understand how it all works:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

struct odomData {
  int x = 3;
  int theta = 2;
};

void GetData( odomData*& msg ) //Passing the pointer by reference, so use the &
{
  int speed = msg->x; //Accessing the data in the struct
  int yaw = (*msg).theta; //Another way of accessing the data that has been passed
  // print
  std::cout << speed << std::endl;
  std::cout << yaw << std::endl;
}

int main( void )
{
  
  odomData d;
  odomData* ptr = &d; //The pointer (of type odomData*) holds the address of the struct d of type odomData
  
  GetData( ptr ); // Call the function to get the data, passing the pointer by reference

  return 0;
}
```

I believe that should be correct. In ROS we simply use `::ConstPtr` to define the message type instead of explicitly using the "`*`" to make it a smart pointer?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-12-20**:
Therefore, ::ConstPtr& can be understood and read as "reference to a shared pointer to a constant message", and ::Ptr& can be understood and read as "reference to a shared pointer to a (modifiable) message".

Why are we assuming that the `msg` variable used in the original question will always take the same value?

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-12-20**:
Hi @jorgemia, your code looks correctly written, but there's no advantage to passing a reference of a raw pointer. There's no savings (in time and memory) there, just extra waste and unnecessary complexity. Don't pass a reference of a raw pointer, pass a reference OR a raw pointer. A reference of a smart pointer has savings because a smart pointer is actually implemented as a class, so passing an instance of a class by reference has additional savings. That being said, it looks like you're trying to mimic passing a smart pointer by reference (even though you're using a raw pointer), in which case, yes, what you've done is syntactically correct. This discussion is more than we should have in comments though. Please post a new ROS question here with that code, or put it on Stack Overflow. Then, leave a link to it here and we can move that part of the conversation to continue under your question.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-12-20**:\

> Why are we assuming that the msg variable used in the original question will always take the same value?

@skpro19, a constant message doesn't mean it is always the same value, it means it cannot be modified inside the function where you receive it. It is read-only. Please go study `const` in C and C++ and `constexpr` in C++. Ex. C++ program. Run and test this code here: https://onlinegdb.com/yG4PaLFRU.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void myFunc(const MyStruct* myStruct)
{
    printf("%i\n", myStruct->a); // ok
    // myStruct->a = 10; // NOT OK!--myStruct points to a const struct so the 
                         // struct cannot be modified here!
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct s;
    s.a = 100;
    myFunc(&s);
    s.a = 200;
    myFunc(&s);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100
200
```

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-13**:
@eRCaGuy Thanks!

In the original answer, @fergs writes this -

```
By passing a const pointer into the callback, we avoid doing a copy. While this might not make much difference for std_msgs::String, it can make a huge difference for sensor_msgs::PointCloud2
```

What has const pointer got to do with avoid doing a copy? Isn't the reason we avoid doing a copy is because we are passing a reference to the pointer variable (msg).

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2021-01-13**:
@skpro19, you are clearly grasping parts of what's going on, but not the whole picture yet. Here's a hypothetical example to hopefully illuminate what he means and what you said. I'd have to write a test program to see actual numbers, but I'll have to do that another day. Here's some made-up numbers to make the point. Let's imagine you have a raw 3D point cloud scan taken by a lidar that has 10000 steps per 360 deg revolution and 64 vertical lasers. Each point is a 4-byte distance reading in mm taken by one of the 64 lasers at one of the 10000 steps. So, the number of bytes in a **single** scan is 10000 steps/rev * 64 lasers * 4 bytes/laser sample = 2560000 bytes = 2.56 MB. If you pass that object into a function it copies **2560000 bytes**! So, you make a smart pointer instead. The smart pointer is, let's say, **32 bytes**. Passing it instead is so much better! But, a raw pointer or a reference is only **8 bytes on a 64-bit processor**. So, pass a **REFERENCE TO the smart pointer**...

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2021-01-13**:
...instead of a **COPY OF the smart pointer** to further reduce how much you copy from **32 bytes** to **8 bytes!**  The smart pointer @fergs is talking about is the **2560000-byte-to-32-byte** copy reduction. The **reference to the smart pointer** you are talking about is the additional **32-byte-to-8-byte** copy reduction.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-14**:
@eRCaGuy Got it.

Would it be perfectly fine if we replace `void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)`  with `void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::Ptr& msg)` ?

**Comment by [romain](https://answers.ros.org/users/161138/romain/) on 2023-07-12**:
@eRCaGuy What is the point of passing a **const pointer to a msg** (or **const reference to a const pointer to a msg**) instead of a **const reference to a message** directly. Where would be the copy in : `void my_callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& msg)` ?

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2023-07-12**:
@romain, these aren't regular C-style raw pointers. They are smart pointers. Read about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170. Also, research and study "memory leaks in C++". Smart pointers prevent memory leaks on dynamically-allocated memory. After studying this, re-read my answer and see if you can understand it better. Your function call is fine to just pass around a reference to some message data, but if that message is *dynamically allocated*, wrapping it in a smart pointer is a good idea to auto-delete it once the smart pointers to it go out of scope.

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2023-07-12**:
@romain, also, go through the many comments above this. I think you'll find a lot of hidden insights.